# Describing the language of this Automaton

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, nondeterminism

[image]

I am trying to describe the above automaton in English. The pattern that I can see is that it accepts any input that starts with $1$ or $0$ with an exact one occurrence of $00$ and ends with 1 or 10. How can I also phrase that it also may end with 00?

Comment: `and ends with 1 or 10` or 110 or 1110…: looks pointless. Ponder 000. (Don't let label D having a different colour distract you.)

Comment: "any input that starts with $1$ or $0$". In fact, every string (over alphabet $\{0,1\}$ starts with $1$ or $0$ except the empty string. "With an exact one occurrence of $00$$", the input cannot be the empty string, making the previous condition superfluous.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Have you considered upvoting and accepting my answer? Please comment if my answer can be improved. (This comment will be deleted upon feedback.)

Answer (score 2):

The automaton accepts exactly the strings that contain exactly one occurrence of $00$ as a substring.

---

The above is the simplest description of the automaton in English. Note that $00$ substring can be at the very beginning of a string or at the very end of a string.